# How do you get a tank without owning one?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

So if you don't have 1.5 million to buy a tank, how do you get one without buying it?

Comment: There is also a sub and fighter heli's on the map after rank 50.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where to obtain a tank](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131217/where-to-obtain-a-tank)

Comment: Gta online not singleplayer/campaign.

Comment: @jimmyplaysdrums This question is for GTA Online, while the other one is for the single-player story mode of GTA V.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you hit rank 30 you can get a cargobob from the island helipad next to the docks where you drop cars off for Simon. If you are lower than that, pick a higer ranked player up and drive them there. They'll spawn a cargobob or fighter heli. With the cargobob, sneak to the far right of the army base entrance and circle  till you find a tank. With the right skills and patience, you can sneak up on one and fly it away. Higher ranked players can remove their wanted level immediatly by calling Lester.